# How to know Webview has been cached in Jetpack compose Android

Tags: android, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show no internet view only if there is no internet and webview i not cached.

```
   var isLoaded by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    // A custom WebViewClient and WebChromeClient can be provided via subclassing
    val webClient = remember {
        object : AccompanistWebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                println("view is $view and url is $url")
                isLoaded = true
            }
        }
    }

    Column(modifier = if (isComingAfterLogin) modifier.padding(bottom = 56.dp) else modifier) {
        WebView(
            state = state,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .gradientBackground(true),
            navigator = navigator,
            onCreated = { webView ->
                webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
                webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                when (themeStyleType.ordinal) {
                    0 -> webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent.toArgb())
                    1 -> webView.setBackgroundColor(Color(0, 0, 0).toArgb())
                }
                webView.settings.defaultFontSize = 1
                webView.settings.textZoom = 80
            },
            client = webClient
        )
        if (isLoaded && !isComingAfterLogin){
            GradientButton("OK", onButtonClick = onNavigationUp)
        }
        if (!isLoaded) {
            Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
            }
        }

        // Check if the page is cached
        val isCached = state.lastLoadedUrl == urlToApply

        if (!isNetworkAvailable(context = context) && isLoaded){
              NoInternetView()
              Toast.makeText(context,"is chached value is 
              $isCached",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
          }
      }
```

How i get the value of iscached is the problem.

I want to show no internet view only if there is no internet and webview i not cached.